# Plot dataframe with years in columns with pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
country,2010,2011,2012
Afghanistan,1,2,3
Belize,5,3,2
England,3,3,4
```

I want to plot this dataframe so that each country is represented by a line in a line diagram, where the x-axis represents the years.

How do I do this?

Comment: Does `df.plot(y = ['2010','2011','2012'], x='country')` do what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately not. That returns a rather weird result actually

Comment: Can you post what your plot should look like, thanks

Comment: It should just plot the value by year, for each country. Like this diagram: http://investing.curiouscatblog.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/manufacturing_output_as_percent_of_gdp_1980-2008.png

Comment: OK but in that example year is the x-axis by the way

Comment: Oh, that's embarrasing. Sorry for the confusing post then, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to reshape the data frame:

```
%matplotlib inline
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rc("figure", figsize=(8,6))

data = """
country,2010,2011,2012
Afghanistan,1,2,3
Belize,5,3,2
England,3,3,4
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
reshaped_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["country"], var_name="year")
df = reshaped_df.pivot(index='year', columns='country', values='value')

df.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Pure awesomeness. Thank you!